# How to create a ViewPager dynamically with fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

How can I create a PagerView dynamically? Without using a xml? Let's say that I have a xml layout like this:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/a_frame_for_pagerview"
             ... >

<!-- I WANT MY PAGERVIEW HERE BUT DYNAMICALLY, NO XML -->

</FrameLayout>
```

It don't need to be a FrameLayout, just used it because I thought it would be the case.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

My main problem is that I have too many pagers that crash because of memory and I want them to be disposed but even I removing the Fragment where the pager is inside, it keeps reference to the older pager(from the first time I create the fragment) where all the fragments are destroyed, so nothing appears.

Comment: how can i do that from my fragment? I want a new ViewPager everytime the fragment is hidden(or removed) and showed(added) again.

Comment: Actually answer of your question is quite long. my short answer would be, assuming you are using a view pager with different data sets, just change its adapter with another adapter filled with dataset(An array list with fragment maybe) and release the previous adapter with it's data sets each time. That way you solved your view pager reference problem. Be careful strong references, which is quite tricky at huge applications. That's all i can say for now. If this solution is not satisfactory for you i might create a longer answer for you within this week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with :

In your XML :

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

In your frament :

```
[....]
mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyFragmentAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
[....]
public class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        YourClassFragment fragment = new YourClassFragment();  
        Bundle args = new Bundle();  

        args.putParcelable("EXTRA_DATA", "VALUE");  
        fragment.setArguments(args);  

        return fragment;  
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return yourNumberOfFragment;
    }

}
```

Comment: what are this "args.putParcelable("EXTRA_DATA", "VALUE"); and fragment.setArguments(args)" about? My main problem is that I have to many pagers that crash because of memory and I want them to be disposed but even I removing the Fragment where the pager is inside, it keeps reference to the older pager where all the fragments is destroyed, so nothing appears.

Comment: args.putParcelable("EXTRA_DATA", "VALUE"); allow you to pass some value for your fragment like idNews=1,idNews=2 ...